# Can apps on an external display be moved to a new space on disconnect?

Tags: display, macos, spaces

I use an external monitor with my laptop while at work but when I'm not working I just use the regular MacBook Pro display. What I would like is for the windows I have open on the external display to be moved to their own space when I disconnect it instead of moving to space 1 on my MacBook. It just gets a little crowded and moving 4-5 windows over to a new space manually every time I disconnect has gotten a little tiresome.

I'm running OS X 10.10 (14A389) on a late 2013 Retina Pro (15") in case anyone was wondering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like if you create a blank space on your laptop side of things and place it in the Desktop 1 spot all the external display apps will go there on disconnect. Only weird thing is when you reset your computer if you aren't plugged into an external monitor then some of the apps seem to move around a little bit, otherwise this method seems to be exactly what I was looking for.

Cheers

Comment: As far as keeping Desktop 1 empty, you can make it easy using Login Items and the "Assign To" options: https://superuser.com/a/1221401/454133

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com)?

[Here](http://joseherran.info/blog/2014/10/11/move-cursor-and-window-through-screens/) is an example of how I deal with moving windows through screens. Must be really easy to modify per your requests in a simple macro.

Comment: Well ideally I'd prefer to not have to do any moving. The external display has it's own dock, it's own menu bar, etc. and is essentially a different space. I just want to add that space to my existing ones on disconnect rather than have to move everything around. This is definitely a quicker method of moving widows around than the standard way on a Mac though, thanks.